# Is cardinality aggregation performance efficient with hundreds of millions of different values

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get count of distinct documents based on a specific field.
The number of different values of that specific field is millions and will maybe scale to even hundreds of millions. Is cardinal aggregation will be efficient enough? if I'll add more shards and nodes, is the performance will improve? or i should try and think of a different way to save my data.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_counts_are_approximate):

> The cardinality aggregation doesn’t scale when working on high-cardinality sets and/or large values as the required memory usage and the need to communicate those per-shard sets between nodes would utilize too many resources of the cluster.

So I wouldn't go that route. Maybe if you explain your use case in a bit more details, we can try to figure our a better data design.

Comment: You got that phrase wrong. they explain why accurate counts are not scalable therefore they are using an approximate counts algorithm.

Comment: Ok, I admit I misread your question and thought you wanted to know if the `cardinality` aggregation was accurate enough even with millions of unique values. The fact remains, though, that you won't get an exact number. I still think you should explain your use case, as there might be other solutions to solve it.

Comment: It's Ok that the result will not be accurate, i'm just worrying about the performance

Comment: I will try it but also wanted to ask if someone knows the answer already

Comment: There are some interesting details in here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20178

Comment: I tested the query on test data with 10+m docs, the time it took was about 15 seconds. adding more shards and increasing memory didn't helped. I ended up saving the data in a different way.

Comment: There you go! Glad you figured it out.